# Reputation re-calc doesn't adjust Badges

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Looking at my profile I have the "Mortarboard" badge but have never met the criteria for it based on rep history.

I believe someone randomly went on an up-vote spree on my profile, the system caught it, and revoked the reputation points but not the badge.

Not that I'm complaining here or anything about having the badge, but it's an oddity none-the-less.

Probably a bug due to an unanticipated thing happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a bug. Badges aren't retracted, but you won't get it a second  time when you meet the criteria again. The old badge will be reused instead.

Comment: I remember reading that badges are now tracked differently, so that in many cases (at least badges associated with a specific post/tag) you will get the next badge normally. I failed to find a reference, though, so I may be mistaken.

Comment: Not being re-awarded it doesn't make much difference here, as mortarboard is one-time-only anyway...

Comment: @John If the badge not disappearing were a bug, it could lead to another bug where you'd get it a second time when you hit the rep cap again. This is a moot point though.